# jquery animate is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, safari

my jquery animation code is working fine in IE and firefox, but it doesnt work in Chrome and safari. any suggestions?

this is my animation code for jquery

```
$('#menu ul li a').click(function (e) {

    /* On a thumbnail click */
    $('li.menuItem').removeClass('act').addClass('inact');
    $(this).parent().addClass('act');

    var pos = $(this).parent().prevAll().length; //.prevAll('.menuItem').length;
    pos = pos - 1;


    $('#slides').animate({ marginLeft: -positions[pos] + 'px' }, 450);
    /* Start the sliding animation */

    e.preventDefault();
    /* Prevent the default action of the link */
});
```

Comment: I use animate({"margin-left": "-350px"}) not marginLeft in my code

Comment: marginLeft is working fine in IE and firefox.

Comment: margin-left not working in firefox. didnt check on other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I remember well jQuery computes well without 'px' when animating or applying css for easier manipulation, and it is more logical because animating is calculation with numbers, not strings. Then isn't it a problem of css property ? Have you tried to set at least a 'position':'relative' or 'display':'block' or 'display':'inline-block' to the element you are animating. Because css needs that type of display for applying margin properties. Try animate 'left' instead of 'margin-left' for example, if it works, it comes from a needed css property for applying margin.

Comment: Because browsers css compliance are VERY different...more it depends trought their different versions...and all of them has different default css properties on dom elements. try with left and tell us it should take about 2 secs.

Comment: I have tried everything you mentioned but slider is not working on chrome and safari.

Comment: well ok...so you tried to animate 'left' property and you assume the elements has a 'position':'relative' property ? I am sorry but I never get this problem with chrome, maybe you could try to make a very simple test separated of all other code, only with the elements you want animate and the animating. And precise the versions of browsers and OS you are testing on, so maybe someone knows one issue about that.

Comment: okay i think i should comment all of my code and uncomment it one by one. i am using windows 7.

Comment: I mean maybe some other stuff in your work is causing interferences. So instead of commenting line per line, try build another simple html with only the most simple elements you wish animate, jQuery lib and your animating code, so it is more easier to debug and see if it works better, then do you know about console.log with Chrome ?

Comment: no i do not know about console.log. i will search it on google. and finally animations are working on chrome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `left` instead of `marginLeft`.